# C++ TerminateProcess function

Tags: c++, windows, process, termination

I've been searching examples for the Win32 API C++ function [TerminateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx) but couldn't find any.

I'm not that familiar with the Win32 API in general and so I wanted to ask if someone here who is better in it than me could show me an example for,

- Retrieving a process handle by its PID required to terminate it and then call TerminateProcess with it.

If you aren't familiar with C++ a C# equivalent would help too.

Comment: Are you just looking for this WINAPI function OpenProcess http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx ?  Putting this together with TerminateProcess shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: No, I want to terminate a running process. That is why I have mentioned that I have to retrieve the PID of it first.

Comment: When someone gives you a link, read it.  Don't just assume from the name what it does.  In fact, OpenProcess creates a process handle, given a PID, which is exactly what you asked for.  @Charles: That should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Evidently it's not the whole answer as the last comment suggest that we need to retrieve the PID from somewhere. @jemper: Which process do you want to terminate? How are you identifying it if not by PID?

Comment: Since you want to terminate a process you didn't start, the first thing I'd ask to give you an answer is how you plan to locate such process. Are you looking for a given executable, or will you show the processes and ask the user, or is it a process that opened a given file, etc? And what if multiple processes fit the pattern?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To answer the original question, in order to retrieve a process handle by its PID and call TerminateProcess, you need code like the following:

```
BOOL TerminateProcessEx(DWORD dwProcessId, UINT uExitCode)
{
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_TERMINATE;
    BOOL  bInheritHandle  = FALSE;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, dwProcessId);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, uExitCode);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return result;
}
```

Keep in mind that TerminateProcess does not allow its target to clean up and exit in a valid state. Think twice before using it.

Comment: How can I get the process's PID?

Comment: What kind of identifier do you have for the process you want a PID for?

Comment: This does not have to be unique. You might have several instances of an executable running at the same time. You can use EnumProcesses to get all instances of a process with a given name or apply some additional selection criteria.

Comment: Beware that this would return immediately. While dying process may still hold some locks for some time. You may need to add a loop with `GetExitCodeProcess` to ensure that the process has already died.