# Kill parent process without administrator rights

Tags: c#, .net, process, kill-process

How can I kill the parent process without administrator rights? Process A creates process B, and in process B I need to kill process A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ TerminateProcess function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443738/c-terminateprocess-function)

Comment: how about using IPC and an exit token instead (this is graceful exit instead of process kill)? or are you unable to edit the source for proces A?

Comment: @lsk Please answer the questions you are asked - Don'tjust say thanks

Comment: "or are you unable to edit the source for proces A?"
what do you mean by "source" of process? Process A and process B run me (they runs by me)

Comment: Are you kidding?? Source as in sourcecode.

Comment: I have source code for both processes

Comment: let me put it this way: can you edit the source code of the executable of A? if not then you should accept the answer that suggests using the taskkill tool, if so then you have other options to end process A gracefully. this info should have been in your question so we can give you more meaningful answers.

Comment: yes, mtijn, i have source code for both applications (for processes). Important to kill it without admin rights

Comment: yes of course, your answer and some others is good. I have added rank for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to ProcessB to signal to ProcessA that it wants to it to stop running. ProcessA can then clean up any resources and exit gracefully (as suggested in the comments to your answer). So how does a Process signal something to another Process? That is called Inter-Process Communication (IPC) and there are loads of ways to do on the same machine or across machines including message buses, web-service, named pipes.

A simple option is a system-wide EventWaitHandle - good example here [Signalling to a parent process that a child process is fully initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187020/signalling-to-a-parent-process-that-a-child-process-is-fully-initialised)

Comment: ok, thank you, Peter. But important question - can it work without admin rights?

Comment: ProcessA is stopping itself running so there are no problems with lack of Admin privileges there.

Comment: This is a good way if there is access to source code of parent process :))

Comment: there is, the author says so in the comments of the question

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true):

> Taskkill
>
> Ends one or more tasks or processes. Processes can be killed by
>   process ID or image name. Syntax
>
> taskkill [/s Computer] [/u Domain\User [/p Password]]] [/fi
>   FilterName] [/pid ProcessID]|[/im ImageName] [/f][/t]
>
> /t : Specifies to terminate all child processes along with the parent
>   process, commonly known as a tree kill.

You can start a process in C# like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

string args = ""; // write here a space separated parameter list for TASKKILL
Process prc = new Process(new ProcessStartInfo("Taskkill", args));
prc.Start();
```

Comment: TerminateProcess makes more sense

Comment: @DavidHeffernan TerminateProcess is nice and all, but you'd have to P/Invoke it

Comment: @harold What's wrong with P/invoke? Spinning up another process is a little bit overkill. What if it's not there?

Comment: And if you don't like P/invoke then isn't it just easier to call `Process.Kill()`?!!

Comment: It is very stupid way to involve another process in order to kill process. And existence of taskkill.exe is not guaranteed (administrator could restrict access to It or remove It at all)

Comment: @Praetor12 and invoking `Process.Kill` is not guaranteed too. What if B process is not run as Administrator?

Answer (score 2):

so you have the source code for both processes. in this case you can use a named system event like a semaphore to gracefully end process A. for example, [construct a named semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hshy7t04.aspx) in process A, pass the name to process B as one of the command line parameters when starting process B. [Open the existing named semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz356skf.aspx) from process B and signal it to let process A know it can end. you could also use taskkill but not ending A gracefully could result in corrupting resources A uses.

Answer (score -1):

All is very simple if you know parentProcessName, then solution is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName ("ParentProcessName")[0].Kill();
```

If not, then it will be a bit harder.

Comment: ProcessB does not have admin privileges to kill other processes.

Comment: Then there are two ways: 1) To run another process from user with administrator's rights 2)"Ask" parent process to terminate itself (if It is your application)

Comment: @Praetor12 but actually he mentioned that he doesn't have administative privilages, so that `Process.Kill` is meaningless here

Comment: @Mr.DDD Taskkill, running form non-privilieged user, will be with the same user privilieges...